# How can I change my login password from private key to user defined password after I logged in my Linux server using putty?

Tags: linux

How can I change my login password from private key to user defined password after I logged in my Linux server using putty so that when I will login to Linux server I can use the user defined password?

Comment: Do you mean how do you configure PuTTY to log in using a password, or how do you configure a server to allow password login via SSH?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the SSH server allows you to login with a password this should work, otherwise you need to have the daemon configured to allow password logins.

**If you need to set a password for your account**

After you login type `passwd`

```
user@host:~$ passwd
Changing password for user.
(current) UNIX password: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

**Then disable the use of key authentication in Putty for the hosts configuation/profile**

http://subatomicsolutions.org/images/putty.jpg

You can still revert to using the SSH key later by configuring it in Putty.

**If you want to prevent the server from allowing logins with your SSH key**

Edit the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and remove your key from the list. Or remove `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to entirely disable key authentication (e.g. if there are other keys in there) for your account. ***Make sure you can login another way first!***

**If the sshd daemon is configured to refuse password logins or root logins**

You'll have to modify it's configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Read `man sshd_config` and read the comments in the config file. If you are trying to login as root with a password, it is likely disabled and will have to be enabled.

**The general idea**

```
# Allow login with password (defaults to yes in openssh I believe)
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Allow root to login with a password (Careful! Potentially bad idea)
PermitRootLogin yes
```

**Then restart the SSH daemon.**

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

**All examples are good for Debian/Ubuntu based distros**

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu (should be similar on other distros, run the commands as root):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, change the line `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes`, then run `/etc/unit.d/sshd restart`.

Then open another putty window and test (so that you can change the configuration back in case there is a problem).

It should ask you for a password next time you log in.